# Is there a way to output parquet files in AWS S3 using AWS Glue job by avoiding the empty $folders generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue

```py
df.write.option("header", "true")\
        .option("quoteMode", "NONE")\
        .option("escape", "\\")\
        .parquet(path=s3_output_path, mode="append")
```

I am using the above code in Glue script to output parquet files.
However I am facing the issue of empty **$objects** created for each folder in S3 bucket

[image]

Comment: These are the placeholders created by hadoop and should not cause any trouble. In case they are creating some problem for your use case, you could remove them once your job has been successfully executed.

Comment: @HarshBafna Thanks. Yes I am aware of it.  However, I dont want to write a script to remove these files but would like to find why these placeholders are not deleted by the job after execution. Please share your code snippet if it is different than how I am using it

Comment: as per my experience with AWS EMR, this files didn't get cleaned only in case of failed jobs. There is nothing wrong with your code. However, I am still missing the problem you are facing because of these files.

Comment: @HarshBafna: The job is succesfull. The problem is that it doesnt affect the files but results in an unclean output. Also, I have files within these folders eg. blocks/courses/year/month/. So these placeholder objects are created under every partition.

Comment: Did you get an answer for your question?